# Convert RGBA565 & RGBA566 image to PNG

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

How do I speed this up? [Image1](https://www.mediafire.com/file/85rb4dgq1ugoyyh/AQUARIUM1.PTX/file) is composed out of binary RGB565 colours (in little endian) and [Image2](https://www.mediafire.com/file/ahh99aaixyg63d5/BACKGROUND1UNSODDED.PTX/file) is composed out of RGB556 colours (in little endian). And put in the input/ folder where the script is located. I can already do the first image but what about the second?
Do I need to use a different image library (preferably in C)?

```
from os import makedirs
from os.path import join as osjoin, dirname
from PIL import Image
def uncompressed2(filename, width, height):
    # BGR565
    byte = open(osjoin(application_path, "input", filename + ".PTX"), "rb").read()
    Image.frombuffer("RGB", (width, height), byte, "raw", "BGR;16", 0, 1).save(osjoin(application_path, "output2", filename) + ".PNG")
    print("wrote " + filename)

def uncompressed3Manual(filename, width, height):
    # BGR655
    byte = open(osjoin(application_path, "input", filename + ".PTX"), "rb").read()
    img = Image.new('RGB', (width, height))
    index = 0
    for y in range(0, height):
        for x in range(0, width):
            a = byte[index]
            b = byte[index + 1]
            img.putpixel((x,y), (b & 248, 36 * (b & 7) + (a & 192) // 8, 4 * (a & 63)))
            index += 2
    img.save(osjoin(application_path, "output3", filename) + ".PNG")
    print("wrote " + filename)

# Make dirs
makedirs(osjoin(application_path, "output2"), exist_ok = True)
makedirs(osjoin(application_path, "output3"), exist_ok = True)

# uncompressed2("AQUARIUM1", 568, 320)
# RGB556 image
uncompressed3Manual("BACKGROUND1UNSODDED", 1580, 640)
```

Image 1:
[image]
Image 2:
[image]
This is what I get if I try BGR;16 for the second image:
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What's an `UNSODDED` image? Why do you call two separate functions? What's the image for exactly - is it the input or the output? If it's the input, where's the output please? If it's the output, where's the input please?

Comment: I'm trying to convert a raw image (just bytes) to png. Unsodded just means without grass. I'm calling 2 functions because there are 2 different encoding formats. The image is used in a game, I want to unpack it and change it. The image is the output, PTX the input. The input are the 2 hyperlinks in the description. Image 1 & Image 2.

Comment: You're never going to get good performance if you have to loop over every pixel in the image.  However, PIL allows you to directly read most any sort of uncompressed image directly, using `Image.frombytes()`; looks like the decoder parameter might be `"BGR;15"` or `"BGR;16"` for your images.

Comment: "BGR;16" worked for the first image but not for the second. See image above.

Answer (score -1):

Heading towards swatting-flies-with-anti-aircraft-gun territory, but you could probably read the data into a numpy array, do the arithmetic with numpy, and build the image from that (if I remember correctly, PIL can take numpy arrays as input). At least that might move the loops inside numpy...

Comment: I would prefer using a default conversion. That's also most likely faster when possible.